# How to make an asynchronous network call but wait for the result on a library class's overriden method with coroutines?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Sorry for the verbose title.

I have a class that extend's okHttp's Authenticator interface where I need inside the overriden authenticate() to make an asynchronous network call to get a refresh token, but I must save the result to shared preferences *immediately*, so I have to block using runBlocking, which I've seen numerous people claiming it shouldn't be used in production code, but it's the only way to get it working for me.

Any ideas if there's a better way to achieve this, or is this an acceptable usage of runBlocking?

```
    class RefreshTokenAuthenticator @Inject constructor(
    private val serviceApi: ServiceApi,
    private val sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences
    ) : Authenticator {

    override fun authenticate(route: Route?, response: 
    Response): Request? {

    if (response.request.url.toString().contains("/refresh")) {
        return null
    }

    runBlocking(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val apiResponse = serviceApi.get().refreshToken()
        sharedPreferences.saveCredentials(apiResponse)
    }.let { isRefreshed ->

        if (isRefreshed) {
            val newToken = sharedPreferences.getToken().orEmpty()
            return response.request.newBuilder()
                .header("Authorization", "Bearer $newToken")
                .build()
        } else {
            return null
           }
       }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, first you should encapsulate `serverApi` and `sharedPreferences` by using the `Repository` pattern then use  `WorkManager` and schedule a repeated work that requests the server for a new refresh token and stores it encrypted in `SharedPreferences` (I preferred `DataStore`) then get saved refresh token from `Repository` and use in `RefreshTokenAuthenticator`.